Wagmi useWriteContract doesnt work all the time
For all the functions i've written to contract using useWriteContract in Wagmi, it reverts atleast 2 times before i refresh and it starts working. For example this function here,
This is the solidity function
function buyDynoTokens(uint256 amount) public {
        buyerBalance[msg.sender] += amount;
        require(
            usdc.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(seller), amount),
            "USDC transfer failed"
        );
        require(dyno.transfer(msg.sender, amount), "DynoToken transfer failed");
    }

This is a simple transfer of mock USDC to get tokens in return
These are my wagmi custom hooks
To approve the amount
import { erc20Abi } from "viem";
import { useWriteContract } from "wagmi";

export const useApprove = () => {
  const { writeContract } = useWriteContract();

  const approveTokens = async (
    tokenAddress: string,
    spenderAddress: string,
    amount: number
  ) => {
    try {
      await writeContract({
        address: tokenAddress as `0x${string}`,
        abi: erc20Abi,
        functionName: "approve",
        args: [spenderAddress as `0x${string}`, BigInt(amount)],
      });
      console.log("Approval transaction confirmed");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error approving tokens:", error);
    }
  };

  return { approveTokens };
};


To check pre-existing allowance
import { erc20Abi } from "viem";
import { publicClient } from "./utils/client";
import { useApprove } from "./use-approval";

export const useAllowance = () => {
  const { approveTokens } = useApprove();

  const checkAllowance = async (
    tokenAddress: string,
    ownerAddress: string,
    spenderAddress: string,
    amount: number
  ) => {
    const allowance = await publicClient.readContract({
      address: tokenAddress as `0x${string}`,
      abi: erc20Abi,
      functionName: "allowance",
      args: [ownerAddress as `0x${string}`, spenderAddress as `0x${string}`],
    });

    if (allowance > BigInt(amount)) {
      return;
    } else {
      approveTokens(tokenAddress, spenderAddress, amount);
    }
  };

  return { checkAllowance };
};


And finally the buy function
import { useWaitForTransactionReceipt, useWriteContract } from "wagmi";
import { dynoBuyerAddress, dynoBuyerAbi } from "../../constants/constants";
import { useAllowance } from "./use-allowance";

export const useBuyDyno = () => {
  const { data: hash, error, isPending, writeContract } = useWriteContract();
  const { checkAllowance } = useAllowance();

  const buyDyno = (
    tokenAddress: string,
    ownerAddress: string,
    spenderAddress: string,
    amount: number
  ) => {
    checkAllowance(tokenAddress, ownerAddress, spenderAddress, amount);

    writeContract({
      address: dynoBuyerAddress,
      abi: dynoBuyerAbi,
      functionName: "buyDynoTokens",
      args: [BigInt(amount)],
    });
  };

  const { isLoading: isConfirming, isSuccess: isConfirmed } =
    useWaitForTransactionReceipt({
      hash,
    });

  return { buyDyno, hash, error, isPending, isConfirming, isConfirmed };
};


This is how i have implemented it in the component
const { address: ownerAddress } = useAccount();
  const { buyDyno, hash, error, isPending, isConfirming, isConfirmed } =
    useBuyDyno();

  async function handleBuy(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const buyData = new FormData(e.target as HTMLFormElement);
    const amount = Number(buyData.get("amount"));

    try {
      await buyDyno(
        mockUsdcAddress,
        ownerAddress as string,
        dynoBuyerAddress,
        amount
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

dynoBuyerAddress is the contract address containing the buy function
And then finally this is my wagmi config
import { http, cookieStorage, createConfig, createStorage } from "wagmi";
import { sepolia } from "wagmi/chains";
import { metaMask } from "wagmi/connectors";

export function getConfig() {
  return createConfig({
    chains: [sepolia],
    connectors: [metaMask()],
    storage: createStorage({
      storage: cookieStorage,
    }),
    ssr: true,
    transports: {
      [sepolia.id]: http(),
    },
  });
}

declare module "wagmi" {
  interface Register {
    config: ReturnType<typeof getConfig>;
  }
}


I have deployed all my contracts to sepolia
When i click on buy on the frontend i get this error
"The contract function "buyDynoTokens" reverted with the following signature: 0xfb8f41b2"
Although Metamask still asks for approving the mock usdc, rest of the function has failed.
Then i refresh and it reverts again. After refreshing a couple of times, The function works one time before going back to reverting 2-3 times again.
